# Object fit and height

Tags: css

I am trying to write code that either 'contains' or 'covers' an image based on browser dimensions. Everything works as expected with the exception that if the height of the window is lesser than the width, the image get cropped even when using contain.

I have the following CSS code:

```
.object-fit_cover { object-fit: cover; width:100%; height:auto;}
.object-fit_contain { object-fit: contain; max-width:100%; height:auto; }
```

My HTML code to show an image

```
<img  ng-src="<myimage>" ng-class="{'object-fit_cover':imageFit==false, 'object-fit_contain':imageFit==true}" />
```

When the height is larger than the width - things are perfect, like this:

[image]

But when I stretch the width to be larger than the height, it crops the image, even if I switch to object-fit:contain

[image]

What I really want is, if I am using class="object-fit_cover" then the image should fill the window and if I switch to using class="object-fit_contain" then the image should always show in its entirety - this does not happen in the second example I sighted above.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using viewport percentage lengths? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths

Comment: Bingo. I needed to add ``style="width:100vw; height:100vh"`` - I'd be happy to accept if you choose to post it as an answer

Comment: Thanks, but it wasn't a proper answer, you did all the work.

Comment: Fair enough, let's share the cookie-of-success - you for showing the path and me for following it through.